# Copy inside a table in prestashop DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prestashop

Im trying to copy the name of a table where the `id_lang` is different in *Prestashop*.

What i want to achive is that i copy the name in same table, from `id_lang=6` to name where `id_lang=8`

I have the SQL query that works fine but i want to do this with a PHP query instead so i can put a cron on it.

Anyone that can help me?

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang a
INNER JOIN ps_product_lang b
  ON b.id_product = a.id_product
  AND b.id_lang = 6
  AND a.id_product > 2218
SET a.name = b.name
WHERE a.id_lang = 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query:

```
Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->execute(
    "UPDATE `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "product_lang` a
    INNER JOIN `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "product_lang` b
        ON b.id_product = a.id_product
        AND b.id_lang = 6
        AND a.id_product > 2218
    SET a.name = b.name
    WHERE a.id_lang = 8"
);
```

If you want to create a cron here is your php file:

```
<?php

// Put the real path to config.inc.php depending on the location of this file
include_once ('../../config/config.inc.php');

try {
    $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->execute(
        "UPDATE `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "product_lang` a
        INNER JOIN `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "product_lang` b
            ON b.id_product = a.id_product
            AND b.id_lang = 6
            AND a.id_product > 2218
        SET a.name = b.name
        WHERE a.id_lang = 8"
    );
} catch (PrestaShopDatabaseException $e) {
    // You might need to get some more informations on this error
    // $error = $e->getMessage();
    $result = false;
}

echo $result ? "ok" : "ko";
```

Comment: I'm glad you find this answer useful. If you think this answers your question, please accept it to mark this thread as solved. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)